# Can I use Microsoft Excel to convert a "ranged" table to a full breakdown table?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

Suppose I have a spreadsheet with the following rows and columns:

```
QTY MIN | QTY MAX  | 1 Color | 2 Color | 3 Color | 4 Color
1       | 10       | $1.00   | $1.50   | $1.75   | $1.90
11      | 20       | $0.90   | $1.40   | $1.65   | $1.80
21      | 100      | $0.80   | $1.30   | $1.45   | $1.70
101     | 1000     | $0.70   | $1.20   | $1.35   | $1.60
```

Is there an easy way to convert this data into a table having a single column for quantity, representing every quantity between the lowest min and the highest max (1-1000)? For example, this is the desired table:

```
QTY | 1 Color | 2 Color | 3 Color | 4 Color
1   | $1.00   | $1.50   | $1.75   | $1.90
2   | $1.00   | $1.50   | $1.75   | $1.90
3   | $1.00   | $1.50   | $1.75   | $1.90
...
```

Not being a frequent Excel user, I am unaware of any specific Excel-based functions to do this, and imagine something exists that would help the process. If not, I'll revert to writing a standalone script to parse a CSV and do this, but I wanted to ask SU first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use [VLOOKUP](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/vlookup-HP005209335.aspx).

You'll need to keep a copy of the source table on Sheet 1.

Sheet 2 will contain your new table. 
Column A will contain 1-Infinity.
Cell B2 will contain `=VLOOKUP($A2,Sheet1!A2:G5,2)`
Cell C2 will contain `=VLOOKUP($A2,Sheet1!A2:G5,3)`
And so on.

You can use the fill down tool to copy the columns B-G.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing inherent in Excel to automagically transform that data but there are a lot of features that would help you do that.

For example to insert multiple rows for the first set from 1-10. Select the row with 11 and choose `Insert` from the pop-up menu. You can press <kbd>F4</kbd> to repeat this action.

To fill down the series of numbers select the `1` then drag down to select the next 9 cells. Then from the `Fill` → `Series` menu you can fill in a series of numbers.

[image: series]

Then select the dollar values and swipe down to select the range of cells and use `Fill` → `Down` (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>)

You could repeat this process for the other rows. I would probably go from one worksheet to another rather than inserting rows but the option is there.

If this a one-time process it's probably quicker to use Excel rather than scripting a solution.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I really appreciate the pointers. I think this is the way to go. Shouldn't take long.